# connect mongodb to a pure js file

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb

is there any way to get data from a DB (MongoDB) to a pure js file?
I want to check if something already exists in the DB and according to this to send info to the server.

Comment: Have you tried using AJAX

Comment: Also usually the server checks to see if it exists then sends a response to the client about it, so if AJAX doesn't work try that

Comment: I tried ajax to transform the data from the js to the server. I want to add a message that the user already exists and for that, I need info from the db

Comment: Ajax? Here's a good resource: [this clicky clicky link](https://dev.to/rmadisetti3/using-ajax-in-conjunction-with-mongodb-12n)

Comment: the problem is that I didn't use jquery